# How to display previous day and next day dates in html using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on some simple Javascript to display the current date with previous and next date links.

my code snippet as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentTime = new Date();

var month = currentTime.getMonth()+1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
var date = month + " " + day + " " + year;

function ShowSchedule() 
{
document.getElementById("today").innerHTML = date;
}

function ShowDay(isNextDay)
{
if(isNextDay)
{
var nextDay = new Date(year, month, day+1);
date = nextDay.getMonth() + " " + nextDay.getDate() + " " + nextDay.getFullYear();
ShowSchedule();
}
else{
var prevDay = new Date(year, month, day -1);
date= prevDay.getMonth() + " " + prevDay.getDate() + " " + prevDay.getFullYear();
ShowSchedule();
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a id = "prev" href="#" onClick="ShowDay(false)">Prev</a>
        </th>
        <th id="today">
        </th>
        <th>
            <a id = "next" href="#" onClick="ShowDay(true)">Next</a>
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>ShowSchedule();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code working for current, previous and next date also, but the problam is if i click on next day link it will get increase for only one day, same thing for previous link also. My requirement is i can able to whatever date i want by clicking previous and next link navigations.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date((new Date).valueOf() + 86350989) //That will always give you tomorrow (jump ahead 24 hours)

new Date((new Date).valueOf() - 86350989) //Will give you yesterday.
```

Here's what's happening:

```
new Date(number) //You're specifying a DateTime object using the milliseconds from unix epoch (January 1, 1970)

(new Date).valueOf() //You're getting the milliseconds from unix epoch.

86350989 //Is the number of milliseconds in a day.
```

Comment: Hi Mushin,Thanks for your reply, Using this also i am able to nvaigate only one previous day and one next day date but not more than one day. Any suggestions plz.

Comment: If this answered your question, it's good etiquette to flag the post as the answer.  It's near the up/down arrows.  Thanks

Comment: a day is 86400000 milliseconds, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```
var d = new Date(); // today
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1); // yesterday:
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); // tomorrow:
```